# Is Grok inactive?

Tags: python, zope, grok

Since the last version is 1.9, released on 2011, but the documentation only covers from 1.0 to 1.5. Also Windows Installers aren't available. It seems that there's poor activity around the framework, also in the mailing list and IRC channel.

Edited the title because of the confusions. Thanks to everyone for the replies.

Comment: You should probably ask this question somewhere on the [Grok community](http://grok.zope.org/community). Any answer you get here is going to be someone's guess or subjective opinion; any answer you get there will be much more useful. (Or, if you get no answer at all, that probably tells you that it's dead.)

Comment: Meanwhile, I doubt that it's actually _deprecated_. Deprecation is something that someone actively does, and makes it obvious. For example, [appscript](http://appscript.sourceforge.net) is deprecated (although [not everyone](https://github.com/mattneub/appscript) is willing to abandon it). A project whose front page starts off explaining why you should use it is not deprecated; it could be active, or so finished that it needs no work, or abandoned.

Answer (score 1):

No, the project has not been deprecated.

Like many open source software projects there is a natural cycle in interest and activity, with the only difference being the speed in which the cycle progresses.

Deprecation is an explicit choice by the maintainers; no such choice has been made. It's just that most interest in the project has moved on elsewhere.